# How to divide input in parallel crc?

Tags: verilog, crc32

I am trying to understand the working of a parallel crc using look up tables, I could get the basic sarwate code running correctly but I am having a lot of confusion when it comes to appending or prepending zeros.

I am trying to use this code for a parallel crc generation but I am confused on how to divide which part of the input data and append zeros.

Please help, I am really stuck here.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code you already have. Also describe what exactly does not work with this code or where you have doubts.

Comment: Sure. I will do that

Comment: FYI: `initial` in table1 should be `always @*`. Otherwise it will only be evaluated at time 0 and likely before receiving the input data.

Comment: @Greg : Thank you,i'll make the changes

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to combine CRCs computed in parallel by looking at the source code for zlib's [`crc32_combine()`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c#L372) routine. You do not need to prepend or append zeros.